# Post-logout redirect in OpenID Connect

Tags: oauth2, connected-apps, open-id-connect, logout

When I log into my application with Salesforce as OpenID Connect Provider (OP), I am able to do so. But, when I try and log out of my application, I am logged out of Salesforce and then redirected to my Salesforce login page `https://{MY_DOMAIN}.my.salesforce.com/`.

**Expected Behavior:**

When a logout request with `post_logout_redirect_uri` is sent to OP, the OP should redirect to this URL after its own logout sequence.

**Actual Behavior:**

When I attempt to log out of the application I am redirected to my Salesforce domain and asked to log in to Salesforce again.

**What I've Tried:**

As per [Documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=security_auth_slo_oidc_idp_configuring.htm&type=5), I've enabled Single Logout on the connected app trying both `https://{MY_KEYCLOAK_DOMAIN}/auth/realms/{REALM}/broker/{IDP}/endpoint/logout_response` and `https://{MY_KEYCLOAK_DOMAIN}/auth/realms/{REALM}/protocol/openid-connect/logout` as the `Single Logout URL` value in the connected app configuration.

I've attempted using the back-channel logout method, but it does not seem to log out of Salesforce using that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've discovered, only front-channel OIDC single logout (SLO) is supported by SF acting as OpenID Connect Provider (OP). This is/can be confirmed via OIDC metadata under `/.well-known/openid-configuration`.

How does front-channel SLO work in OIDC? From the [spec](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-frontchannel-1_0.html#OPLogout):

> OPs supporting HTTP-based logout need to keep track of the set of
> logged-in RPs so that they know what RPs to contact at their logout
> URIs to cause them to log out. Some OPs track this state using a
> "visited sites" cookie. OPs contact them in parallel using a
> dynamically constructed page with HTML `<iframe src="frontchannel_logout_uri">` tags rendering each logged-in RP's
> logout URI

No mention of `post_logout_redirect_uri`. (OIDC session management spec used to talk about `post_logout_redirect_uri` but it was removed in the latest draft).

As the help doc you reference states, the front-channel logout URI the spec talks about is retrieved by Salesforce from the connected app's Single Logout field.

For post-logout redirect from Salesforce, you can configure a logout URL at the org level  via `Setup => Session Settings => Logout Page Settings => Logout URL`. This will apply to all connected apps. The value of this config setting could point to a service based on your own custom code running wherever that can further examine the request and perform appropriate post-processing steps.

NB: OIDC session mgmt + SLO (both front and back channel) specifications are still drafts and not final.

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer. I saw the option for `Setup => Session Settings => Logout Page Settings => Logout URL`. We have other connected apps on this org, so we cant just set it to the Keycloak logout endpoint. I was hoping there would be a simple answer, but thanks for the advice on creating a custom service to manage post-logout logic.